# Why iOS 11Custom UINavigationItem titleView and leftBarButtonItem are varying from iOS9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

My Puzzle is "Why iOS 11Custom UINavigationItem titleView and leftBarButtonItem are varying from iOS9?".

When I customize titleView and leftBarButtonItem in navigationItem of my HomeViewController, I found something different here.

The following code successfully places the custom leftBarButtonItem and custom titleView in the navigation bar.

```
    // customize leftBarButtonItem
_customLeftItemView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40);
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGes = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(clickLeftItemAction:)];
[_customLeftItemView addGestureRecognizer:tapGes];

UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_customLeftItemView];
leftItem.width = 60.0f;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;

// customize titleView
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 40)];
searchBar.placeholder = @"Please search address";
searchBar.delegate = self;
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
```

The `_customLeftItemView` is like the figure below.[customLeftItemView In Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtwIv.png)

Above the code executed，the appearance difference between iOS11 and iOS9, like the figures below.[iPod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXGGV.png)[Simulator iPhone8 iOS11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGwlU.png)

When I checked the difference through Debug View Hierarchy tool, I found `searchBar` occupies the entire area of the `UINavigationBarContentView`  and `UISearchBarTextField` on the right side of the `UIButtonBarStackView` when App ran in iPhone 8. however when App ran in iPod(iOS 9), `searchBar` didn't occupy the entire area of the `UINavigationBarContentView`, it is on the right side of the `UIButtonBarStackView`. the code `_customLeftItemView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40);` is effective in iOS9, so the leftBarButtonItem width is fixed, if run in iOS11, it loses effectiveness. the difference like the figures below.[iPod Debug View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKFCM.png) [iPhone8 Debug View Hirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knb6D.png)

Could you help me with this?
Thanks for your help.